# Taxonomical Navigation Browsing

Tags: navigation, taxonomy, managed-metadata

I am new to the Taxonomical and meta data usage in SharePoint 2010 and would be grateful if someone could point my in the right direction to what I am trying to achieve.

I am trying to create a Taxonomical navigation that will allow me to pull in related content based on relevant pages the user browses to. The taxonomical navigation will be displayed as a sub-menu. How would I be able to output this to the page based on the site/page the user is viewing?

I am planning on having a list of managed terms through Term Store Management for users to assign meta-data to their documents etc.

Can meta-data only be assigned to lists or can they also be assigned to pages as well?

Answer (score 1):

Metadata can be assigned to pages, documents, or any list items. You can define the metadata for the required item by creating the content types, When you create these content types, you can specify term stores that will be used in the metadata column, thus controlling the metadata. Out of the box, there is metadata browsing available. You should try that and see if it will meet your needs prior to customizing.

Comment: So will metadata browsing show related meta data based on the part of the site the user is browsing? I will need to customise the meta data browsing to fit in with the site design.

Answer (score 1):

Pages like other kinds of content are stored in a Library, and are based on a content type, so yes, you can add metadata columns to pages.

Which kind of page are you referring to: Publishing, Web Part, Wiki, etc? The process of customizing Publishing pages with Page Layouts is a bit diffrent than customizng non-publishing pages like Wiki and Web Part pages.

Comment: I will be customizing Publishing and Web Part pages.

Comment: For publishing pages, you need to create a custom Page Layout and bind it to a related content type. You can put metadata fields on the related content type. Publishing pages are always created in the "Pages" library. For non-publishing pages, you will probably want to sub-class the existing Web Part Page and Wiki Page content types to create your own, and add metadata columns. Then add or replace the content types on the Site Pages library to allow users to create pages based on your content types.